# How to cache memory in JBoss as 7.1 when server restarts?

Tags: java, jboss7.x, openshift

How to cache (I don't know if cache is the right word for it.) memory when my openshift's JBoss server restarts. Basically I have taken data from database and I am storing it in a linked list. I don't want to lose this data when my server restarts, I want Jboss to regain this data after it restarts. How can I do it? I am new in the server side java world, please guide me.

Comment: Simple way to store your List in flat file using Object IO Stream, Persist when your application context destroy and rebuild list when Application context created.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options here:

1.)  Convert your linked list to json with gson and store it in the database or in a file on the server in your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

2.)  Rebuild the data using the original data from the database on server restart (why would you not want to do this?)

Comment: I don't want to rebuild it from database because I am doing some operations before storing data in linked-list. I don't want to do them again everytime my server restarts.

Comment: How often does your server restart? That shouldn't really be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a scaled application on OpenShift you are going to run into problems where the data is only cached on one of the servers. You should look into using something like [Redis](http://redis.io/) to cache your data.